# Problems with the work of preloader vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, preloader

I'm trying to make showing preloader when i go from one component to another. I use this [preloader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-loading-overlay). I create file `loader.js` and write there:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Loading from 'vue-loading-overlay';
import 'vue-loading-overlay/dist/vue-loading.css';

Vue.use(Loading);

let loader = Vue.$loading.show({
    loader: 'dots',
    color: '#5D00FF',
    zIndex: 999,
}); 
function loaderStart() {
    loader;
}
function loaderEnd() {
    loader.hide();
}

export default {loaderStart, loaderEnd}
```

`loader,js` i import to the `index.js` and there i write when i want to call loader start but it does not starting(withoun `if` in `beforeResolve` preloader is working). Here is `index.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Authorization from '@/components/Authorization'
import Main from '@/components/Main'
import loader from './loader'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
    routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Main',
        component: Main,
    },
    {
        path: '/authorization',
        name: 'Authorization',
        component: Authorization
    }
  ]
})
router.beforeResolve((to, from, next) => {
    if(to.path) {
        loader.loaderStart()
    }
    next()
});
router.afterEach((to, from) => {
    loader.loaderEnd()
});
export default router;
```

Please, help me find the problem

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that `if` condition?

Comment: @MatJ when we go to another rourer run method, smth like this

Comment: Remove that if then?

Comment: @MatJ then i see only preloader, it cover rest of the content on page and it don't stop

Answer (score 4):

1. Your current `loader` will appear just once because you called `show` method once as well. You need to invoke `show` method every `loaderStart` call and store the loader:

   ```
   let loader = null;
   function loaderStart() {
       // it would be better to extract these values as constants 
       loader = Vue.$loading.show({
            loader: 'dots',
            color: '#5D00FF',
            zIndex: 999,
       }); 
   }
   function loaderEnd() {
       loader.hide();
   }
   ```
2. Probably you have some async components since you added loader to routing logic, so you should use the `beforeEach` hook instead of the `beforeResolve` one.

   ```
   router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
       loader.loaderStart()
       next()
   });
   router.afterEach((to, from) => {
      loader.loaderEnd()
   });
   ```

[Loader API docs](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-loading-overlay#vueloadingshowpropsdataslots) (`show` method)

[Vue-router guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)

[Vue-router navigation flow](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#the-full-navigation-resolution-flow)

Comment: @МаксимБуяков here is a codesandbox example (timer is just for the demo) https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-routing-example-syx2u

Comment: Yes, it turned out that it just did not have time to show yourself) with set time out it looks okay. But could you please tell me one more thing: if i want to show preloader, but dont want to show it 2 seconds every time(it shoud show only time that page loading) i gust need to write some code which "know" when page loading end set it in set time out?

Comment: No, you shouldn't use `setTimeout` at all in that case, I added that just for demo to show that the loader works. If you don't have some lazy-loaded components it will never be shown. In your example in the question, your page components will be bundled in a single assembly(file) that's why your loader wasn't shown.